# What do you call embedded dotts/lines which indicate sliding in GUI?

Tags: gui-design

I have attached an image which explains which element I am talking about. I am trying to find out it's proper name.

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Handle". However, it's usually prefixed by its intended use: "drag handle", "resize handle", "scroll handle", etc.

[image: Example image]

(From left to right: scroll handle, rotate handle, resize handle, sort handle.)

Answer (score 3):

Im don't think there is an official term for these. Use of the word "Drag" definitely makes sense but I dont know if "handle" is the right description either as it is visually nothing like a handle.

I have also used and heard "Grip" or "Grip Bars"... Maybe we can coin a new term, What about "Drag Grip"?

Comment: "Grip" is the most logical thing to me. It's a skeuomorphic element that (should) indicate draggability, when you have a real thing you're supposed to grab like that it's called a grip.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "sliding", do you mean dragging? If so, I would call that a "grab handle".

Comment: is that the proper name? I couldn't find any similar images by searching "gui grab handle"/"graphical grab handle"/"iphone grab handle" in google.

Comment: Microsoft tends to refer to it as a "resize handle", when used in the context of resizing a window. "Handle" is certainly the usual term whenever dragging is involved. It probably wouldn't be appropriate for activating something with a click though.