# How can I indicate that an area is swipable?

Tags: swipe, cards

I have a mobile timeline with cards, each card can be swiped to the right to display interaction options. We feel that it's not evident to the user that there's anything there, the 3 dots we've added are meaningless.

[image]

Is there some form of indication that means "swipable" that we could give the user, beyond giving them a guided tour of some sort.

Comment: That question isn't related to this one, voting to keep this open

Answer (score 2):

**Dont!**

Swipeable things are in design meant to **shorten** quick interactions which are listed in a *table view*

All the things you have displayed here can be easily put on the card itself

Besides the point: *facebook* and *twitter* make sense, *hand* doesnt. I have no idea what it does

[image: this is how it should look]

This is how it should look, and be used. Its like using a slidebar to enter your password, its just fundamentally wrong.

Comment: What if I have a magic the gathering card with an obvious backside? I'm sure there's other things you can reasonably swipe than table views. ;) The hand is contextual within the app, it doesn't really matter what it does.

Comment: @KitSunde is it clear that the backside of a card should be accessed by swiping?  Not to me.

Comment: @dan1111 Does it seem less clear than a table view being swipable?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using three vertical lines like so:
[image]

You can read in this other question on UX.SE about how these lines are typically used to represent pullable/draggable areas and why:
[What do the 3 close horizontal bars (not hamburger menu) represent and what is the origin of the design?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80463/what-do-3-close-horizontal-bars-not-the-hamburger-menu-represent-ux-wise-an)

> It is a skeumorphic depiction of notching, indicating that the area can be pulled/dragged. Similar to the notching on the end of the gun slide (providing extra grip to the fingers). - Bowen