# What is the name of this UI element?

Tags: modal-view

I tried to find out the name of this, but I can find nowhere.

So, I just call it 'Modal View Handler'

Is that correct name? anything else?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: At least related, [What do the 3 close horizontal bars (not hamburger menu) represent and what is the origin of the design?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/80463/57088).

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be asking about the horizontal grey bar that indicates further information may be available off screen. They are often referred to as **handles** or (swipe) **indicators**. In non-touch interfaces, they may be dragged. For instance, the text box I am typing in has a handle at the bottom for resizing. Sidebars and windows also often have handles for resizing. Toolbars may have handles for repositioning. Etc.

[maxathousand](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125985/#comment202261_125989) observes:

> Note also that these are somewhat skeuomorphic in that they are similar to a bar-style handle on a physical drawer. This real-world analogy alludes to the method of interaction, by implying that it can be dragged or pulled in much the same way.

Comment: Note also that these are somewhat skeuomorphic in that they are similar to a bar-style handle on a physical drawer. This real-world analogy alludes to the method of interaction, by implying that it can be dragged or pulled in much the same way.

Comment: https://uxdesign.cc/handlebars-in-ui-design-4b36af67733b "On a high level, handlebars are useful whenever two discrete blocks of information need to be rearranged strictly straight along x or y axis. Handlebars also serve one other key purpose — they act as signifiers to make invisible gestures visible."

Comment: @MadalinaTaina The problem with that article is immediately apparent in the subtitle, "A new kind of element..." Handles are nothing new. They are nearly as old as the GUI. The writer ignores the established usage history and makes up his own limitations and guidelines. For example, "steering"? How is this interface like a bike or car? Is it going somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but confirm the name and provide some info.

Answer (score 0):

It is called swipe menu, Apple use it in their new iphone Xs/r UI instead of the home button

Comment: The widget indicated (horizontal grey bar) has more uses than just to reveal a swipe menu.